# PHP change date format from long date with time to basic date

Tags: php, web

I currently have the date in the format: Day, day month year 24hr with seconds and timezone. I want to get this into Y-m-d.

Current Date:

```
Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34  0000
```

Final Date:

```
2018-03-23
```

I am using PHP to do this. The date is hard coded so I am unable to call the date() function at all.

Comment: You mean that you a variable like `$str = "Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34  0000"`?

Comment: @Syscall that is correct yes!

Comment: Why are you unable to call the date function? How have you tried to use the date function?

Comment: @Andreas The date is hard coded as a static value upon submission. I need to change the format to ingest it into another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
$str = "Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34  0000";
$str = trim( preg_replace( "/[0-9\+]*$/", "", trim($str) ) );
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($str) );
```

Output:

```
2018-03-23
```

Comment: 2xtrim? Ok.. now I have seen it all.

Comment: Accepted as answer due to readability, simplicity and ease. Thanks!

Comment: Readability? Didn't see that one coming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to transform your date:

```
$str = "Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34  0000";
$str = preg_replace('~\s(\d{4})$~', '+$1', $str); // change '0000' to '+0000'
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("D, d M Y H:i:s  O", $str) ;
echo $d1->format("Y-m-d") ;
// or 
// echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($str)) ;
```

Outputs:

```
2018-03-23
```

Or, as pointed out by @Andreas, you could use `substr()` to remove timezone:

```
$str = "Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34  0000";
$str = substr($str, 0,-5) ;
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($str)) ;
```

Comment: `str_replace(' 0000', '+0000', $str)` isn't that a bit to hardcoded? This answer is only valid in one specific case.

Comment: @Andreas Agree. I'll improve it.

Comment: I would rather use `substr($str, 0,-5)` still quite hardcoded but at least flexible on timezones

Comment: @Andreas Right, good solution. I've change to a `preg_replace()`. Do you think that could be more flexible?

Comment: Sure. But regex is probably too powerful for such a simple task. But it will work. Regex is probably safer than substr in case the timezone by some reason is missing. But if you can trust the format then substr will be faster, well... not that you will ever notice it. But you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this code

```
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime(preg_replace( "/[0-9]+$/", "", "Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34  0000")) );
```

This will output the same answer you required

Answer (score 0):

If the date is hardcoded as you say, that means it will always have a three lettered day, a comma then the date, then time and timezone.
The length of the string should be the same always.
This can be used to an advantage.

```
$str = "Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:28:34 0000";

Echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime(substr($str,5,11)));
```

Here I use only the `23 Mar 2018` in the strtotime and date function.
No need for regex or trimming or adding + or - to timezones.